# How to fix wyswig with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

Ok, This is just an example, but every asp.net project I've been working on has this problem..

How can anyone agree that what I see in designer is even near to what I get in browser?? 
Is there any way to fix this?

The following image comes from asp.net project constructed in vs2012 using html5 but the problem exists since 2008 at least..

[image]

Comment: You should show us a smaller example, and show us the  markup for that example.

Comment: Any markup that use server side panel controls will render different in designer than in browser- just put a MultiView and you will see.. it is not a big deal when you work with small isolated examples but the more you add the more diff you get and at some point the designer wysiwg become irrelevant just as you can see in the example..

Comment: What if it only does this for _your_ markup, on _your_ computer? Give us a small example which you believe will work on _our_ computer, then we'll try to reproduce it.

Comment: The most simple example in vs2012 ultimate -> new solution / new project -> choose asp.net web forms application as your template, look at your designer, good! now execute the application and look at your browser - is it same? is what you seen in your designer is what you got in your browser?

Comment: Have you tried using the Page Inspector? It seems to be producing exactly what I see in IE, down to the responsive page design. In particular, the page reflows and various items change visibility based on the page size.

Comment: But when I use page inspector it means the web design is non editable.. this is good to know but it is not a solution to the problem I describe.

Comment: That's a good question. Did you find a solution?

Comment: no solution, maybe in next vs they'll fix it..